# Modal Dialog box does not close with stopPropogation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have the following dialog box:

```
<div class="modal fade PSettings" id="ModalMsg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
    $(".btn").click(function (evt) {

    var wID = $('#MPID :selected').val();

    if (wID.length == 0) {

      evt.preventDefault();

      $('#ModalMsg .modal-body').html('<p><b>Please select a valid name from the drop down list.</b></p>');

      $('#ModalMsg').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true
      });

      evt.stopPropagation();

    }
});
```

The issue that I am running into is that I like to show the dialog box and have the ability for the user to click on the Close button. Nothing happens when the user clicks on the close button.

After the close button is clicked, I like to stop propagation as clicking on the button fires another action.

Comment: Stopping propagation will stop it from *bubbling* not stop other event handlers

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks. How do I stop another event from proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need to operate with all events/listeners if you just want just control hide/show modal event. Use 'hide.bs.modal' event for modal. It fires evety time you are trying to close modal. And returning true or false in this function will enable or disable closing modal.

```
$(".modal").on("hide.bs.modal", function(){
    return false; // you should return true if you want to close dialog, otherwise you should return false 
                // so change 'false' in my example to your conditions
});
```